# How to test angular service from component function?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I am trying to test network call happening in a component.

I want to call ngOnInit function in test class, which calls another functions which subsequently have a network call through a service function.

Here is my TestComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-cmp',
  templateUrl: './test-cmp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-cmp.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

constructor(private logger: LoggingService, public teststore: TestStore, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.testProductList = new Array();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }, 3000);
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  private init() {
      this.getProductListForVault();
  }

  // this functions make network calll

  getProductListForVault() {
    this.teststore.getProductInfoData().subscribe(productInfoData => {
      console.log('got product data', productInfoData);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my testing class

```
describe('TestComponentTest', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let logger: LoggingService;
  let testStore: TestStore;
  let cdr: ChangeDetectorRef;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [TestStore]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

it( 'calling onInit should call getsitelogin', inject([HttpTestingController, TestStore],
    (httpMock: HttpTestingController, service: TestStore) =>  {
   spyOn(service, 'getProductInfoData');
   spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit').and.callThrough();
   component.ngOnInit();
   expect(service.getProductInfoData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));

});
```

The test is failing with the following results

> Expected spy getProductInfoData to have been called once. It was
>   called 0 times. Error: Expected spy getProductInfoData to have been
>   called once. It was called 0 times.

Why it is happening? Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Should search something like spyOne subscription or unit test rxjs topic.

Comment: 'getProductInfoData' method is in service 'TestStore' and in the test, I see that the method is referred to from service 'PasswordVaultStore'.

Comment: I am editing it , thank you !